# Count property of array in PowerShell with pscustomobjects

Tags: powershell

If the array has only one CustomObjects and the Count property is null. **Why?**

If use only strings, the Count property is one.

```
function MyFunction
{
    $Objects = @()
    $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "Hallo"}
    # $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "World"}

    $Objects
}

$objs = MyFunction
Write-Host "Count: $($objs.Count)"
```

Output: `"Count: "` because `$objs.Count` is `null`

```
function MyFunction
{
    $Objects = @()
    $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "Hallo"}
    $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "World"}

    $Objects
}

$objs = MyFunction
Write-Host "Count: $($objs.Count)"
```

Output: `"Count: 2"`

**Behavior is different if I add strings**

```
function MyFunction
{
    $Objects = @()
    $Objects += "Hallo"
    # $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "World"}

    $Objects
}

$objs = MyFunction
Write-Host "Count: $($objs.Count)"
```

Output: `"Count: 1"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force the function to return an array even if the nested array is constructed of one object.

```
function MyFunction
{
    $Objects = @()
    $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "Hallo"}
    # $Objects += [pscustomobject]@{Label = "World"}
    return ,$Objects
}
```

That comma makes an explicit conversion to an array even if the supplied `$Objects` is already an array of more than one object. This forces a construction of an array with one element. Outside, Powershell does [unboxing](https://superuser.com/questions/414650/why-does-powershell-silently-convert-a-string-array-with-one-item-to-a-string) of a one-item array, so you'll get an array if there was one, so this method works around default Powershell behavior for working with one-item arrays. You experience `Count` being 1 because in Powershell 3.0 [Microsoft fixed one-item arrays by adding `Count` property to every object](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2012/03/19/Counting-objects-in-PowerShell-3.0.aspx) so that indexing of one object returns `Count` as 1, and for `$null` zero is returned, but the `PSCustomObject`s are excluded from this as a natural reason declares that they can contain their own `Count` properties, thus no default `Count` property is included for a custom object. That's why you don't get `Count` if there's only one object.

The behavior of `,` can be seen on the following example:

```
function hehe {
    $a=@()
    $a+=2
    $a+=4
    $b=,$a
    write-verbose $b.count # if a variable is assigned ",$a", the value is always 1
    return ,$a
}
```

Output:

> PS K:> (hehe).count
>
> VERBOSE: 1
>
> 2

Comment: As a note, a single pscustomobject has a count of 1 in PS 7.